# Set data validation for all rows (even new ones) in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is this possible? I can set data validation for the entire column, but when I add new rows, it doesn't have the same rule.

Comment: use onChange trigger on your GS script.

Answer (score 0):

install an onChange trigger to handle setting the validation to the new rows. [copyDown](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copydown/lipbbdpmkcbplmfnbholpabinnnkbbda?hl=en) Add-on may be doing this.

Comment: So have an onChange trigger that then just copies the validation to the end of the page?